# KDB - collapse columns in market data table

Tags: kdb

I have a market data table with ordered price and quantity data, for a range of market providers and symbols, e.g.

```
b:([]symbol:();provider:();px1:();px2:();px3:();qty1:();qty2:();qty3:())
```

where px1 is top of book at quantity qty1, px2 next best price etc. Sample data may then be

```
`EURUSD;`EBS;1.1;1.2;1.3;1000000;2000000;4000000
```

I would like to collapse the px[n] and qty[n] columns into single columns, the format then being;

```
rb:([]symbol:();provider:();px:();qty:())
```

with the sample data then reading;

```
EURUSD, EBS, 1.1, 1000000
EURUSD, EBS, 1.2, 2000000
EURUSD, EBS, 1.3, 4000000
```

What would be the best approach to achieving this? As a newbie I was thinking along the lines of using dictionaries;

```
q)px:book `px1`px2`px3
q)qty:book `qty1`qty2`qty3
q)d:`px`qty!(px;qty)
q)flip d
px  qty
-----------
1.1 1000000
1.2 2000000
1.3 4000000
```

... but I'm sure there are better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following if you can't restructure your original table definition.

```
q)b
symbol provider px1 px2 px3 qty1    qty2    qty3
---------------------------------------------------
EURUSD EBS      1.1 1.2 1.3 1000000 2000000 4000000
EURUSD ECS      1.1 1.2 1.3 1000000 2000000 4000000
q)ungroup {rm _x,'flip enlist[y]!enlist flip x rm:cols[x]where cols[x] like string[y],"*" }/[b;\`px\`qty]

symbol provider px  qty
---------------------------
EURUSD EBS      1.1 1000000
EURUSD EBS      1.2 2000000
EURUSD EBS      1.3 4000000
EURUSD ECS      1.1 1000000
EURUSD ECS      1.2 2000000
EURUSD ECS      1.3 4000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Connor's answer is probably most canonical, however `ungroup` is still an iteration over the table which is by definition slower than direct list manipulation. Iteration is unavoidable in many cases but here you can construct the result table directly from the lists of the input table like this:

```
flip `symbol`provider`px`qty!(
                (3*cb)#b`symbol; 
                (3*cb:count[b])#b`provider; 
                (b[`px1],b[`px2],b`px3); 
                (b[`qty1],b[`qty2],b`qty3))
```

Here the result table has the first two columns `symbol` and `provider` repeated three times and the `px` column is a concatenation of `px1`, `px2` and `px3`, same for `qty`.

Of course this method does not produce the same row order as `ungroup` but the interesting bit is it runs ~40 times faster (about 40ms for 1m rows, ungroup is about 1600ms).

If required to preserve the order of records, we can number them and then sort:

```
`a`b _ `a`b xasc flip `a`b`symbol`provider`px`qty!(
    (3*cb)#til[cb]; 
    raze cb#/:(til 3); 
    (3*cb)#b`symbol; 
    (3*cb:count[b])#b`provider; 
    (b[`px1],b[`px2],b`px3); 
    (b[`qty1],b[`qty2],b`qty3))
```

Here the `a` and `b` columns provide indexes for sorting and are later removed from the result. The run time of this is about 180ms on 1m rows so still about 9 times faster than the ungroup method. Of course the presence of sorting will make this algorithm worse than linear however there is a lot of margin there for it to be still faster up to about 100m rows (can't test that right now unfortunately)

Comment: You can use ```raze flip b[`px1`px2`px3]``` to maintain the ordering of the price and quantity columns and index into the symbol and provider columns using ```(`symbol`provider#b)where count[x]#3```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get it done using `flip` and `ungroup` :

```
q)b:([]symbol:`eurjpy`eurusd;provider:2#`ebs;px1:10+2?.1;px2:11+2?.1;px3:12+2?.1;qty1:100+2?10;qty2:100+2?10;qty3:100+2?10)

symbol provider px1      px2      px3      qty1 qty2 qty3
---------------------------------------------------------
eurjpy ebs      10.05641 11.04464 12.02366 109  103  107
eurusd ebs      10.01925 11.08214 12.07947 104  104  102

q)ungroup select symbol, provider, px:flip (px1;px2;px3) , qty:flip (qty1;qty2;qty3)  from b
symbol provider px       qty
----------------------------
eurjpy ebs      10.05641 109
eurjpy ebs      11.04464 103
eurjpy ebs      12.02366 107
eurusd ebs      10.01925 104
eurusd ebs      11.08214 104
eurusd ebs      12.07947 102
```